# joining the contents of three files into one

Tags: awk

I have three files as shown below.

a1.txt

```
>1BS3
MDEKRRAQH
>2ERT
>3a56
NEVE
```

a2.txt

```
>1BS3
QSKGGILS
>2ERT
INNWIV
>3a56
RRRRDK
```

a3.txt

```
>1BS3
>2ERT
PDSSM
>3a56
ILSKASDYIQELRQSNHR
```

I would like to combine the above three files into another file anew.txt. How can I do this?

Desired output

```
>1BS3
MDEKRRAQHQSKGGILS
>2ERT
INNWIVPDSSM
>3a56
NEVERRRRDKILSKASDYIQELRQSNHR
```

I would like to get the output in the above order.

Comment: Note these awk answers use associative arrays. There is no inherent order while iterating over the keys of an array. If this is important for you please let us know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Inherent order is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk program maintains the order of the keys. It keeps the keys seen in a numerically indexed array

```
awk '
    /^>/ {
        key = $0
        if (!(key in val)) {
            keys[++n] = key
            val[key] = ""
        }
        next
    } 
    { val[key] = val[key] $0 } 
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            print keys[i]
            print val[keys[i]]
        }
    }
' a{1,2,3}.txt
```

```
>1BS3
MDEKRRAQHQSKGGILS
>2ERT
INNWIVPDSSM
>3a56
NEVERRRRDKILSKASDYIQELRQSNHR
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
awk '/^>/{sel=$0;next}{a[sel]=a[sel]$0}END{for (i in a) print i RS a[i]}' a[123].txt
```

That says, if the first character is ">", set the record selector (my "sel" variable) to the current line, and ignore rest of processing. If the line doesn't begin with ">", append the current line to the currently selected line. At the end, print everything out.

Sample output:

```
>3a56
NEVERRRRDKILSKASDYIQELRQSNHR
>1BS3
MDEKRRAQHQSKGGILS
>2ERT
INNWIVPDSSM
```

Comment: Not sure why, bit I get all output in on long line, not 6 as in my post.

Comment: Error found, you need to remove the "\" in `/^\>/` and set it to `/^>/`

Comment: Mmmm, weird! No idea why that would be, but thanks for testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '!/^>/ {a[s]=a[s] $0} {s=$0} END {for (i in a) print i RS a[i]}' a1 a2 a3
>2ERT
INNWIVPDSSM
>1BS3
MDEKRRAQHQSKGGILS
>3a56
NEVERRRRDKILSKASDYIQELRQSNHR
```